# php regex special character

Tags: php, regex

I have:

```
$regExge = "/(?!((<.*?)))\b(Öffnung)\b(?!(([^<>]*?)>))/s";
$replacege = "<a href=''>Öffnung</a>";
```

And I used preg_replace to replace Öffnung string to html `<a href=''>Öffnung</a>`

```
$content = preg_replace($regExge, $replacege, $content);
```

But it not working, only working with normal string.

There any way? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to indicate that your pattern should cover an encoding which includes the special characters.  UTF-8 is one option here, and can be indicated by using `/u` at the end of the pattern:

```
$regExge = "/(?!((<.*?)))\b(Öffnung)\b(?!(([^<>]*?)>))/su";
$replacege = "<a href=''>Öffnung</a>";            //  ^^^
$content = preg_replace($regExge, "stuff", $replacege);
print $content;

<a href=''>stuff</a>
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can try this modified version.

```
$content = "Offnung  Öffnung s;ldjfjkasÖffnung";
$regExge = "/Öffnung/";
$replacege = "<a href=''>Öffnung</a>";
$content = preg_replace($regExge, $replacege, $content);

echo $content;
```